# How to use a function to modify sql results presentation?

Tags: php, sql

I am wondering if anyone can help? I am trying to output SQL in a table and I want to use functions 'slot' and 'groupnum' to modify the presentation of the output. When I try the code below the results are printing out in an unformatted way above the table rather than in it. Is there any fix for this?

```
  // Table header.
                        echo '<table>
                        <tr><td><b>Time Slot</b></td>
                        <td><b>Group</b></td>
                        </tr>';
                        // Fetch and display the records:
                        while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                            echo '<tr>
                            <td>' .slot ($row9['slotid']). '</td>
                            <td>' .groupnum($row9['groupid']). '</td>
                            </tr>';
                        }
                        echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
```

Comment: Where's the `table` element? If you are storing that then it makes sense you are outputting here. Append the values, don't echo; or echo everything...

Answer (score 0):

Is this working?

```
echo '<table>'; // Open the table
while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<tr>
          <td><code>' . slot($row9['slotid']) . '</code></td>
          <td><code>' .groupnum($row9['groupid']) . '</code></td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
```

Comment: No luck with that Matei, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the opening tag of the table element.

```
echo '<table>'; // Open the table.
while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>' .slot ($row9['slotid']). '</td>
    <td>' .groupnum($row9['groupid']). '</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
```

Comment: Thanks Yasen.....sorry I have it included, but that doesn't seem to be what is causing it.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that gets generated from your PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an echo statement in the function rather than return, so the code above is okay. The problem was with the functions.

```
//Right way
 function groupnum ($group){

    return "Group $group";
    }

//Wrong way
function groupnum ($group){

    echo "Group $group";
    }
```

Comment: You went to minimal with your example.

Comment: 1936. Richard Bach. “The simplest things are often the truest.”